# Problems trying to add blur effect and dilation effect on SurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I'm trying to Gaussian Blur to live video preview and than add a Dilation Effect to it.

I've tried combining the code and it doesn't seem to work right.

It's just doing the dilation effect but I don't see the blur.

```
// Gaussian Blur code
+"   vec2 singleStepOffset = vec2("+UNIFORM_TEXELWIDTH+", "+UNIFORM_TEXELHEIGHT+");\n"
+"   int multiplier = 0;\n"
+"   vec2 blurStep = vec2(0,0);\n"
+"   vec2 blurCoordinates[9];"
+"   for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {\n"
+"     multiplier = (i - 4);\n"
+"     blurStep = float(multiplier) * singleStepOffset;\n"
+"     blurCoordinates[i] = "+VARYING_TEXCOORD+".xy + blurStep;\n"
+"   }\n"
+"   vec3 sum = vec3(0,0,0);\n"
+"   vec4 color = texture2D("+UNIFORM_TEXTURE0+", blurCoordinates[4]);\n"
+"   sum += texture2D("+UNIFORM_TEXTURE0+", blurCoordinates[0]).rgb * 0.05;\n"
+"   sum += texture2D("+UNIFORM_TEXTURE0+", blurCoordinates[1]).rgb * 0.09;\n"
+"   sum += texture2D("+UNIFORM_TEXTURE0+", blurCoordinates[2]).rgb * 0.12;\n"
+"   sum += texture2D("+UNIFORM_TEXTURE0+", blurCoordinates[3]).rgb * 0.15;\n"
+"   sum += color.rgb * 0.18;\n"
+"   sum += texture2D("+UNIFORM_TEXTURE0+", blurCoordinates[5]).rgb * 0.15;\n"
+"   sum += texture2D("+UNIFORM_TEXTURE0+", blurCoordinates[6]).rgb * 0.12;\n"
+"   sum += texture2D("+UNIFORM_TEXTURE0+", blurCoordinates[7]).rgb * 0.09;\n"
+"   sum += texture2D("+UNIFORM_TEXTURE0+", blurCoordinates[8]).rgb * 0.05;\n"
+"   gl_FragColor = vec4(sum, color.a);\n"

// Dilation Effect
+"   vec2 step = vec2("+UNIFORM_TEXELWIDTH+", "+UNIFORM_TEXELHEIGHT+");\n"
+"   vec4 stepIntensity[dilationSize];\n"
+"   for(int i = 0; i < dilationSize; i++) {\n"
+"     stepIntensity[i] = texture2D("+UNIFORM_TEXTURE0+", "+VARYING_TEXCOORD+" + step * float(i - dilationRadius));\n"
+"   }\n"

+"   vec4 minValue = vec4(1.0);\n"
+"   for(int i = 0; i < dilationSize; i++) {\n"
+"     minValue = min(minValue, stepIntensity[i]);\n"
+"   }\n"
+"gl_FragColor = minValue;\n"
```

I expected it to blur it to than dilate it but it just dilates the image.

Comment: Hi issistsupport! Welcome to StackOverflow :) Your code does not appear to be a minimal working example. It looks like you are building shader code in a meta-program somehow. This makes it unnecessarily hard for us to spot the mistake. Often simply the process of reducing your problem to a minimal working example will give you enough insight in what is going wrong that you do not need any more help and in the other cases it will help us a lot helping you solve the issue, so please edit your post and give us a better idea of what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes.  It's a 2-pass example. I'll add the project on github for example.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes. If I comment out the dilation pass the blur is there.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ok thanks, I'll take a look.

Comment: *"I've tried combining the code..."* / *"If I comment out the dilation pass..."* - Do mean the code in the question is one single fragment shader?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @issistsupport If you would read your own code carefully, then you would see that this can't work. `gl_FragColor` is set after the blur part (`gl_FragColor = vec4(sum, color.a);`) and is overwritten after the dilation part (`gl_FragColor = minValue;`) - so the blur part is useless. The dilation has to be implemented in completely separated passes.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks for your help.